# TkInter is hoarding more and more ram

Tags: python, tkinter

I am creating a script to check the status of some of my computers but noticed that over time the Tkinter window is accumulating more and more resources. Is there any way to fix this?

```
import subprocess
import time
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import gc

ip_addresses = ["192.168.1.83", "192.168.1.93", "192.168.1.93", "192.168.1.92", "192.168.1.95", "192.168.1.103", "192.168.1.105"]
i= 0
if i == 0:
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Online")
    root.geometry("500x300")
    i+1

label_texts = [f"{ip_address} -> unknown" for ip_address in ip_addresses]
labels = [tk.Label(root, text=label_text, font=("Arial", 16), fg="#FF0000") for label_text in label_texts]
for i, label in enumerate(labels):
    label.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

def check_ip_status(ip_address, label):
    try:
        subprocess.check_output(f"ping {ip_address} -n 1", shell=True, timeout=5)
        label.config(text=f"{ip_address} -> online", fg="#00FF00") # Green
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError:
        label.config(text=f"{ip_address} -> offline", fg="#FF0000") # Red
    except subprocess.TimeoutExpired:
        label.config(text=f"{ip_address} -> offline (timeout)", fg="#FFA500") # Orange

def check_all_ip_statuses():
    processes = []
    for i, ip_address in enumerate(ip_addresses):
        label = labels[i]
        process = subprocess.Popen(f"ping {ip_address} -t", shell=True, stdout=subprocess.DEVNULL)
        processes.append(process)
        thread = threading.Thread(target=check_ip_status, args=(ip_address, label))
        thread.start()

    root.after(5000, check_all_ip_statuses) 
    gc.collect() 

    # Close all subprocesses
    for process in processes:
        process.kill()
        process.communicate()

check_all_ip_statuses()
root.mainloop()
```

I've tried to force the garbage collector, kill all processes and to clear the labels every so often but nothing stops tkinter from hoarding more and more ram

-------------Update---------

I've changed the subprocess call to pythonping

```
import pythonping
import time
import tkinter as tk
import threading
import gc

ip_addresses = ["192.168.1.83", "192.168.1.85", "192.168.1.93", "192.168.1.92", "192.168.1.95", "192.168.1.103", "192.168.1.105"]

i= 0
if i == 0:
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Online")
    root.geometry("500x300")
    i+1

def create_labels():
    global labels
    labels = [tk.Label(root, text=f"{ip_address} -> unknown", font=("Arial", 16), fg="#FF0000") for ip_address in ip_addresses]
    for label in labels:
        label.pack(padx=10, pady=5)

def check_ip_status(ip_address, label):
    response = pythonping.ping(ip_address, count=1, timeout=5)
    if response.success():
        label.config(text=f"{ip_address} -> online", fg="#00FF00") # Green
    else:
        label.config(text=f"{ip_address} -> offline", fg="#FF0000") # Red

def check_all_ip_statuses():
    for i, ip_address in enumerate(ip_addresses):
        label = labels[i]
        thread = threading.Thread(target=check_ip_status, args=(ip_address, label))
        thread.start()

    gc.collect() 
    root.after(1000, check_all_ip_statuses) 

create_labels()
check_all_ip_statuses()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What is the point of the `subprocess` call in `check_all_ip_statuses`?  You don't do a thing with that information.  Do you know there is a `pythonping` module that can do a simple ping without requiring subprocesses?

Comment: Hi @TimRoberts thank you for that, replaced the `subprocess` with `pythonping` but sadly I am still getting memory issues

Comment: Try adding `daemon=True` t o the `threading.Thread` calls. Otherwise, python will keep the thread in a list that is processed on process exit.

Comment: Thank you @tdelaney added daemon=True to the threading, but it changed basically nothing with the ram usage

Comment: Unfortunately, this code won't work because you can't do any Tk operations (specifically, `label.config`) from a secondary thread.

Comment: I might suggest you use something like "guppy" to profile your memory usgae.

Comment: @TimRoberts: Well, you can. Sometimes. And then sometimes everything breaks. You *shouldn't* do it, but people get lazy and sometimes it works, right up until it doesn't.

Comment: Why is `check_all_ip_statuses` launching a bunch of `subprocess`es you never use?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried to find out why you version is filling up memory, but I'm not there yet.
Right now I couldn't find out how to use all the memory analyzing tools in a practical way to find the culprit in your source.

So, I created another version of your app, the way I would do it using an OOP approach.

```
import sys
import threading
import time
import tkinter

import pythonping


class PingHost(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip, idx):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.start_time = time.time()
        self.ip = ip
        self.idx = idx
        self.message = ''
        self.success = False

    def run(self) -> None:
        result = pythonping.ping(self.ip, count=1, timeout=5)
        if result.success():
            self.message = f'{self.ip} -> online'
            self.success = True
        else:
            self.message = f'{self.ip} -> offline'
            self.success = False


class App(tkinter.Frame):
    IP_ADDRESSES = [
        '192.168.80.101', '192.168.80.111', '192.168.80.123', '192.168.80.124', '192.168.80.125', '192.168.80.126',
        '192.168.80.127', '192.168.80.128'
    ]
    COLOR_ONLINE = '#00FF00'
    COLOR_OFFLINE = '#FF0000'
    FONT = ('Arial', 16)
    PING_THROTTLE = 10  # delay until a ping thread restarts

    def __init__(self, tk_root: tkinter.Tk):
        super().__init__(tk_root)
        self.root = tk_root
        self.root.protocol('WM_DELETE_WINDOW', self._on_quit)

        self.labels: [tkinter.Label] = []
        self.procs: [threading.Thread] = []

        self._create_widgets()

        self._ping_all_ips()
        self._monitor_procs()

    def _create_widgets(self):
        for ip in self.IP_ADDRESSES:
            string = f'{ip} -> unknown'
            label = tkinter.Label(self.root, text=string, fg=self.COLOR_OFFLINE, font=self.FONT)
            label.pack()
            self.labels.append(label)

    def _ping_all_ips(self):
        for idx, ip in enumerate(self.IP_ADDRESSES):
            self._start_ping_proc(ip, idx)

    def _start_ping_proc(self, ip, idx):
        ping_proc = PingHost(ip, idx)
        ping_proc.start()
        self.procs.append(ping_proc)

    def _monitor_procs(self):
        proc: PingHost
        for proc in self.procs:
            age = time.time() - proc.start_time

            if proc.is_alive():
                continue

            if age < self.PING_THROTTLE:
                self._update_labels(proc)
                continue

            self._update_labels(proc)
            self.procs.remove(proc)
            self._start_ping_proc(proc.ip, proc.idx)
        self.root.after(1000, self._monitor_procs)

    def _update_labels(self, proc):
        if "online" in proc.message:
            self.labels[proc.idx].configure(text=proc.message, fg=self.COLOR_ONLINE)
        else:
            self.labels[proc.idx].configure(text=proc.message, fg=self.COLOR_OFFLINE)

    def _on_quit(self):
        self.root.quit()
        sys.exit()


if __name__ == '__main__':
    root = tkinter.Tk()
    root.title('oop threading test')
    root.geometry('400x400')
    app = App(root)
    root.mainloop()
```

This was running the whole night yesterday, with memory constantly around 12MB
I've got a lot of theories why this is working and yours is not, but I can't proove any of it atm.

So if anyone can shed light, it would be highly appreciated.

I'll update if I find more.

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for the explaination and the code cleanup. But sadly it still takes more and more memory over time, after about 30 minutes it's taking more than 500MB of RAM

Comment: There are a couple of significant problems with this answer.  Starting new threads is not going to use up the memory of the host process.  They're all going to exit eventually, and since `check_all_ip_statuses` returns, there will be no references to the thread objects, and they will be cleaned up.

Comment: To be honest, it was kinda late yesterday and it seemd like I fixed it. I also found a bug in my code that I fixed now. But still it only slows down the time it takes to fill the ram. I'll have to check again why this is happening.

Comment: I updated my answer with my own version of what your code would be doing. I could not find out why the memory is filling up. If I ever do I'll update

Comment: Hello @Ovski, I've been using this version of code for the past 48 hours and it's running like a charm. I think the issue was due to to not using this part `if __name__ == '__main__':` somehow the code was running again and again in a loop. This is why I had to implement the IF statement on the window creation because when converted to an EXE it was opening a lot of windows untill it ran out of cpu and ram resources.
Let me know if that would be the cause.

Comment: @LabiteQ No, I don't think it has something to do if the check for `__main__`. I assume it could have something to do with the update of the labels from inside the thread. I rewrote your original source to use a Ping class the same way I did it in my own version and the problem seems to be gone. I added another answer using your original code but with my updated partsa and some explanation. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

So this version is your code, with some updates.

I think I finally understand this part you added:

```
i= 0
if i == 0:
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.title("Online")
    root.geometry("500x300")
    i+1
```

This is not needed, as your main application does not repeat itself. The `root.mainloop()` is in fact a loop in itself, but does not restart your application over and over again so you can remove it.

As for your comment about `if __name__ == '__main__':` would fix it, not it would not. This is meant to prevent your script from executing if it is imported.

```
print('I will print if this gets imported')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    print('this will not print, if this gets imported, but will if it is executed as a script')
```

---

I created a Ping class that extends threading.Thread so I can add attributes to the thread and then run it.

So the main thing that is different form your code, is that I check all running threads in the `check_all_ip_statuses` function and just continue if the thread is not finished. If it is finished, I'll read out the `response` attribute to update the lables.

This way the labels are not updated from inside the thread and this seems to fix the memory leak problem.

```
from typing import List

import pythonping
import tkinter as tk
import threading


class Ping(threading.Thread):
    def __init__(self, ip_address, idx):
        super().__init__()
        self.daemon = True
        self.ip_address = ip_address
        self.idx = idx
        self.response: bool = False

    def run(self):
        response = pythonping.ping(self.ip_address, count=1, timeout=5)
        self.response = response.success()


def create_labels():
    global labels
    labels = [tk.Label(root, text=f"{ip_address} -> unknown", font=("Arial", 16), fg="#FF0000") for ip_address in
              ip_addresses]
    for label in labels:
        label.pack(padx=10, pady=5)


def start_threads():
    for i, ip_address in enumerate(ip_addresses):
        thread = Ping(ip_address, i)
        thread.start()
        threads.append(thread)


def check_all_ip_statuses():
    for thread in threads:
        if thread.is_alive():
            continue
        if thread.response:
            labels[thread.idx].config(text=f"{thread.ip_address} -> online", fg="#00FF00")  # Green
        else:
            labels[thread.idx].config(text=f"{thread.ip_address} -> offline", fg="#FF0000")  # Red

        new_thread = Ping(thread.ip_address, thread.idx)
        new_thread.start()
        threads.remove(thread)
        threads.append(new_thread)

    root.after(1000, check_all_ip_statuses)


ip_addresses = ["192.168.1.83", "192.168.1.85", "192.168.1.93", "192.168.1.92", "192.168.1.95", "192.168.1.103",
                "192.168.1.105"]

labels: List[tk.Label]
threads: List[Ping] = []

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Online")
root.geometry("500x300")

create_labels()
start_threads()
check_all_ip_statuses()
root.mainloop()
```

As [@ShadowRanger](https://stackoverflow.com/users/364696/shadowranger) mentioned in one of the comments of your question, about if it is okay to update labels from a thread:

`@TimRoberts: Well, you can. Sometimes. And then sometimes everything breaks. You shouldn't do it, but people get lazy and sometimes it works, right up until it doesn't.`

Seems like he is right.